# Pedal floored and my ibiza 1.6 mpi 2018 with 53000 milage can't reach max speed of 150km/h

Tags: seat-ibiza

I have a problem with my ibiza 1.6 mpi engine 110 hp. I can't exceed 150 km/h but in inclined roads i hardly reach it  170 km/h with a cut in engine what do think the problem is due to although the computer shows everything is ok.

Comment: Serviced it lately? oil, filters? checked the brakes?

Comment: Everything is alright oil filter air filter I have also changed spark plugs.

Comment: Notice that the cars behaviour under 150km/hspeed is very normal

Answer (score 1):

The technical specs for your vehicle are listed here:

[Technical specs](https://www.auto-data.net/en/seat-ibiza-iv-1.6-mpi-105hp-13469)

They list a MAXIMUM speed of 187 km/hr.  So your 170 km/hr is close enough to that figure that I suspect there is nothing wrong.  The 187 figure was likely obtained under controlled conditions at a track where you are running on a public road with varying conditions.

This is not exactly a "performance" vehicle as the 105 HP listed is quite low for a vehicle that weighs more than 1000 kg.

Comment: I have I reached 150 km/h but 170 I couldn't reach it in flat road but in descending one with cuts in the ignition I think